# OnSelectionChange listner does not work for the first time on a new sheet

Tags: excel, office-js

Officejs excel's OnSelectionChange listner does not work for the first time on a new sheet. But this happens only when we open the sheet for the first time. After which it works fine. Could anybody help me out to understand the working.

Update: This happens only in Excel web

Update: Please find the video attached for reference https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dBXH74Plu5TwA6ViUf6KlgI8CJZQscPg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: could you please share the sample code? i would like to investigate this issue.

Comment: Refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events) `onSelectionChanged` event is for cell selection change. If you need to intercept sheet activation then see the first in the list `onActivated` event [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#onactivated)

Comment: Hello @RaymondLu please run the following project to understand the scenario. [link](https://gitlab.com/devloprNaveen/excel-addin-sample) . Try selecting a range for the first time after opening a sheet.

Comment: Any updates @Reymond Lu

Comment: We downloaded your code and it seems we cannot run successfully on our side, but we look into your code. we guess it might be an issue related to OnInit, could you please try refers to this document? and see if it helps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=word-js-preview#functions.

Comment: Or it would be helpful if you could share the Script Lab gist, therefore we can repro in our side.

Comment: Hello @RaymondLu please try this gist [link](https://gist.github.com/devloprNaveen/992ddd40042888f7792b82b5a6ad7d5a). And please note that this happens only in excel web

Comment: I just have a try for this gist, it works as expected on my excel online. not observe this issue here.

Comment: @RaymondLu please use the vedio link shared in the question as update as a reference to this issue. I have used the same gists in chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your detail information, now I can repro this issue. I created a bug 4233860 to track this issue.

Comment: Thank you @RaymondLu can I get a reference link for the created issue. Just to check regularly for an update

Comment: Sorry naveen, the bug is a reference to an internal database. so it cannot be accessed from external users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to make sure that viewers will have an answer for this if anyone is facing the same problem. It is a issue in office js Excel API. It has been raised internally. Have a good day.